# HDHomeRun TV Tuner with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I've been trying to read the RTP feed from my HDHR tuner with zero success. Does anyone have experience with this?

GStreamer:

```
gst-launch --gst-debug=udpsrc:5 udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,format=(fourcc)I420, width=(int)720, height=(int)480,encoding-name=(string)RAW,sampling=(string)YUV,pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)8/9, framerate=(fraction)30000/1001, interlaced=(boolean)true" ! gstrtpbin ! rtpvrawdepay ! filesink location=/tmp/output
```

- I got the capabilities via autodetection somehow, at some point.

HDHR:

```
hdhomerun_config 1310DA25 set /tuner2/target udp://192.168.5.102:5000
```

When I try to send via RTP (rtp://192.168.5.102:5000, instead of using UDP, as above), I get a UDP error every time, no matter what the capabilities, whenever it sinks to gstrtpbin:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
```

I'm assuming this means that capabilities don't match between linked pads.

When I use the UDP scheme (originally, above), I don't get any errors, but no data moves through the pipeline.

--gst-debug on various elements at various levels didn't give me anything useful.

VLC works perfectly, whether I'm sending to rtp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:nnnn and receiving on rtp://:nnnn, or sending to udp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:nnnn and receiving on udp://:nnnn.

Any thoughts?

Also, is GST not able to automatically identify capabilities of the RTP stream? I don't know how I tripped over it (in order to get the capabilities, above), but it doesn't seem very intuitive. It seems like that if VLC (super-versatile) could do it, GStreamer (also super-versatile) could do it.

Thanks.

Dustin

By the way, I got this by using playbin2:

```
dustin@dustinlenovo:/tmp$ gst-launch --gst-debug=playbin2:5 playbin2 uri=udp://192.168.5.102:5000
0:00:00.021952272 32470  0x9683400 LOG                 playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:1318:gst_playbin_uri_is_valid:<playbin20> checking uri 'udp://192.168.5.102:5000'
0:00:00.022006314 32470  0x9683400 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:1372:gst_play_bin_set_uri: set new uri to udp://192.168.5.102:5000
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.022144060 32470  0x9683400 LOG                 playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3895:gst_play_bin_change_state:<playbin20> clearing shutdown flag
0:00:00.022164495 32470  0x9683400 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3790:setup_next_source:<playbin20> setup sources
0:00:00.022194614 32470  0x9683400 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3477:activate_group:<playbin20> activating group 0x9711318
0:00:00.022208169 32470  0x9683400 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3498:activate_group:<playbin20> making new uridecodebin
0:00:00.022597792 32470  0x9683400 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3456:group_set_locked_state_unlocked:<playbin20> locked_state 0 on group 0x9711318
0:00:00.023812556 32470  0x9683400 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:2317:gst_play_bin_handle_message:<playbin20> Ignoring async state change of uridecodebin: uridecodebin0
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock





0:00:14.542698212 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3214:autoplug_continue_cb:<playbin20> continue autoplugging group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad0, video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188: 1
0:00:14.542910589 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad0, video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
0:00:14.550811109 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb64189b0
0:00:14.551117538 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad0, video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
0:00:14.551202471 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory mpegtsdemux
0:00:14.713355113 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3214:autoplug_continue_cb:<playbin20> continue autoplugging group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad1, audio/x-ac3: 1
0:00:14.713401299 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad1, audio/x-ac3
0:00:14.713622715 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb6418b80
0:00:14.714048757 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad1, audio/x-ac3
0:00:14.714097628 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory pulsesink
0:00:14.714125521 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3344:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we found a sink
0:00:14.714151129 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3350:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we found an audio sink
0:00:14.714177845 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3393:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we have no pending sink, try to create one
0:00:14.724957778 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad1, audio/x-ac3
0:00:14.725003694 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory ac3parse
0:00:14.725687536 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad2, audio/x-ac3, framed=(boolean)true, channels=(int)[ 1, 6 ], rate=(int)[ 8000, 48000 ], alignment=(string){ iec61937, frame }; audio/x-eac3, framed=(boolean)true, channels=(int)[ 1, 6 ], rate=(int)[ 8000, 48000 ], alignment=(string){ iec61937, frame }
0:00:14.725996661 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb6458eb0
0:00:14.728966979 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3214:autoplug_continue_cb:<playbin20> continue autoplugging group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad3, video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)2, systemstream=(boolean)false: 1
0:00:14.729094763 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad3, video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)2, systemstream=(boolean)false
0:00:14.730460890 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb6418620
0:00:14.731074426 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad3, video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)2, systemstream=(boolean)false
0:00:14.731165683 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory mpegvideoparse
0:00:14.744258860 32470 0xb643be90 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3214:autoplug_continue_cb:<playbin20> continue autoplugging group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad5, video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)2, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true: 1
0:00:14.744409010 32470 0xb643be90 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad5, video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)2, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:14.744667670 32470 0xb643be90 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb4c00950
0:00:14.744743720 32470 0xb643be90 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad5, video/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)2, systemstream=(boolean)false, parsed=(boolean)true
0:00:14.744758143 32470 0xb643be90 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory mpeg2dec
0:00:14.854031750 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3214:autoplug_continue_cb:<playbin20> continue autoplugging group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad7, audio/x-ac3: 1
0:00:14.854191602 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad7, audio/x-ac3
0:00:14.854649600 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb6471880
0:00:14.855619479 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad7, audio/x-ac3
0:00:14.855700091 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory pulsesink
0:00:14.855776440 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3344:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we found a sink
0:00:14.855877980 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3350:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we found an audio sink
0:00:14.855955069 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3393:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we have no pending sink, try to create one
0:00:14.861079720 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad7, audio/x-ac3
0:00:14.861206558 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory ac3parse
0:00:14.861928499 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad8, audio/x-ac3, framed=(boolean)true, channels=(int)[ 1, 6 ], rate=(int)[ 8000, 48000 ], alignment=(string){ iec61937, frame }; audio/x-eac3, framed=(boolean)true, channels=(int)[ 1, 6 ], rate=(int)[ 8000, 48000 ], alignment=(string){ iec61937, frame }
0:00:14.862580662 32470  0x95e5720 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb646de20
0:00:14.864351517 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3214:autoplug_continue_cb:<playbin20> continue autoplugging group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad9, audio/x-ac3, framed=(boolean)true, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, alignment=(string)frame: 1
0:00:14.864560656 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3049:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> factories group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad9, audio/x-ac3, framed=(boolean)true, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, alignment=(string)frame
0:00:14.865104298 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3059:autoplug_factories_cb:<playbin20> found factories 0xb4101e40
0:00:14.865443547 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad9, audio/x-ac3, framed=(boolean)true, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, alignment=(string)frame
0:00:14.865580106 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory pulsesink
0:00:14.865655838 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3344:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we found a sink
0:00:14.865725210 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3350:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we found an audio sink
0:00:14.865796342 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3393:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> we have no pending sink, try to create one
0:00:14.871464068 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3268:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> select group 0x9711318 for '':decodepad9, audio/x-ac3, framed=(boolean)true, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, alignment=(string)frame
0:00:14.871598227 32470 0xb643bf50 DEBUG               playbin2 gstplaybin2.c:3271:autoplug_select_cb:<playbin20> checking factory a52dec
```

Dustin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GStreamer, but there seems to be consistent difficulty getting from the MPEGTS data to having the decoded-video ready for rendering. I believe the standard MPEGTS plugins choke on malformed frames, as does VLC.

So, if you just want to push the raw MPEGTS data from RTP into mplayer, it'll work fine (mplayer is awesome at decoding an MPEGTS stream containing error):

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5011 caps="application/x-rtp, media=video, payload=33, clock-rate=90000" ! fdsink | mplayer -
```

The value for the "payload" capability comes from the "RTP Audio/Video Profile" for MPEGTS-wrapped MPEG2 streams in RFC 3551. VLC probably attempts to decode under a few of these codes in order to effortlessly receive some RTP streams, such as from a HDHomeRun, and thus avoiding the requirement of an annoying SDP file.

On the other hand, if you don't mind using the HDHomeRun tools to get the MPEGTS data, then GStreamer will view it perfectly.

Easy version:

```
hdhomerun_config FFFFFFFF save /tuner0/ - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Specific version (cap filtering is used to make it clear what data is moving):

```
hdhomerun_config FFFFFFFF save /tuner0/ - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! video/mpegts ! tsdemux ! video/mpeg ! queue ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! xvimagesink
```

Obviously, the examples aren't concerned with the audio streams (video is always a higher priority and the source of the greatest error/risk, at least to me).

The Fluendo guys tell me that their GStreamer plugins should account for error. I have yet to test this. Their plugin also only works inside of GStreamer .10 .

EDIT

This is the command-line to "watch" a HDHomeRun feed. Note that the port-number and the program-number will need to be set for whatever you're watching, and the "A52" AC3 library must be installed along with the corresponding "a52dec" "bad" plugin:

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=5011 caps="application/x-rtp, media=video, encoding-name=H264, clock-rate=90000" ! \
    gstrtpbin ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux program-number=12 name=demux \
        demux. ! queue ! ac3parse ! a52dec ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! volume ! autoaudiosink \
        demux. ! queue ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! xvimagesink
```

Note that you can get a really informative flowchart by using the GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR environment variable combined with playbin (if you have all of the required plugins available).

Comment: It turns out that GStreamer and VLC aren't choking on malformed data. Rather, I was testing with over-the-air programming, and, apparently, the PMT packets are being stripped by "zap" or are otherwise not present. mencoder/mplayer must be doing extra work to figure-out what's missing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607860/gstreamer-with-mpeg-ts-video4linux-atsc-dvb-recording/14620654#14620654 .

Comment: As a correction to the comment above, zap has a parameter "-p" that will cause the PMT packets to not be filtered. Hence, the MPEGTS will be fully correct and well-composed. I'm using "azap", and, unlike its three siblings, it has very poor "-h" help. Plus, the "-p" parameter is not identified in the manpage (at least in the version I have).

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with this for a few days I was able to get this working on my Jetson TK1 linux board. You don't need to use hdhomerun_config or open up a rtp / udp stream. From the HDHR you can just grab the stream via http (if you are using a HDHR PRIME).

The below is the following I needed to dump a channel to a file for a POC. Most important part is "video/x-raw,format=I420" or you will get an error. omxh264enc is extremely picky on the frame size, and with I420 you can use any size.

```
# 10.10.10.100 is the IP of the HDHR
# v588 is the example virtual channel to grab on the HDHR
# Audio is encoded to aac @ 192k

sudo gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="http://10.10.10.100:5004/auto/v588" is-live=true ! decodebin name=demux demux. ! queue ! audioresample ! audioconvert dithering=0 ! "audio/x-raw,channels=2" ! voaacenc bitrate=192000 ! mux. matroskamux name=mux streamable=true ! filesink location=output.mkv demux. ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,profile=high ! h264parse ! mux.
```

Now I would like to and use flvmux + rtmpsink, but i'm not sure how to build the pipe.